# ...who is considered at high enough risk for an extra dose

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is an excerpt from [a PBS news article](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/health/fda-backs-pfizer-covid-19-boosters-for-seniors-high-risk?fbclid=IwAR3YH9TR7m_GnG1VRsxrMYnf-kn8Z9TG6B5_D6upSYnlpoKvbk09-QzhUJc).

> Ultimately the committee must decide who is considered at high enough
> **risk** for an extra dose.

I think an extra dose of vaccine is not a harmful or dangerous thing and the 'risk' in bold refers to 'risk of getting COVID-19'. (Of course, there are vaccine safety issues.)

I wonder which of the above and the following sentences delivers a clearer meaning.

*Ultimately the committee must decide who is at high enough risk to be considered for an extra dose.*

Comment: It doesn't mean quite the same thing. Original - there is a risk level where an extra dose is given. Committee decides if it thinks so and so is at that level? Your change - there is a risk level where somebody thinks about giving an extra dose. Committee decides if so and so is at that level. Then the decision has to be made whether or not to give the extra dose.

Comment: They do mean the same thing. The first sentence means 'Ultimately the committee must decide who is considered at high enough risk [of death or serious illness if they get Covid] for an extra dose [of vaccine to be appropriate]'.

Comment: They do mean the same thing. The article's slant was good for a laugh, though.